# TeeChart printing with C++ Builder XE5 not the same as preview

Tags: c++builder, teechart

C++ Builder XE5, 32 bit

1. Drop TChart object on form
2. Right click and select EDIT CHART
3. Click the add button, click OK
4. Click on the word PRINT
5. Click the 'Print' button.

The printed graph looks nothing like the preview.  I've tried a few different types of graphs and none print anything like the preview.  The preview looks perfect, the printed graph is ENLARGED, the title on the paper is almost an inch high, the numbers for the left axis are huge (about 3/4" high), the graph itself is only 2 inches wide by about 4.5 inches high.

Here is the printout  www.rcscoringpro.com/tracks/Chart.pdf

Thanks for looking!

Doug

Comment: The link you posted doesn't return me anything

Comment: Is this what you are getting? http://i62.tinypic.com/313hpi1.png

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed with the free update here:

http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29708

Comment: The update fixed it, thank you very much for helping!